# 3 different price rules for shipping depinding of attributes in Magento CE 1.9

Tags: price, shipping

we need to set 3 different prices for shipping depending on attributes. We have refrigerated food with a price rate for shipping and then dry food and food gift basket with different shipping prices. Is there a way to set 3 different prices of shipping per attribute or per product in Magento CE 1.9 - 1.9.1?

Thank you in advance for your collaboration!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't want to write a module for this. Therefor I suggest you look at the module Owebia shipping 2 which is available for free. The configuration is quite advanced and you can also use attributes to calculate shipping if you're willing to spend some time getting used to the format of the configuration.

Also please use google, I'm pretty sure you would have found Owebia ;)